# A widget contained in more than one cell in a QGridLayout is not centered

Tags: qt, alignment, qgridlayout

The question says it all.

I have a 5x3 grid.

It looks like this

```
row 0:  buttonA--buttonA--buttonA   nothing   buttonB--buttonB--buttonB

row 1:  empty row

row 2:  buttonC  nothing  buttonD   nothing   buttonE  nothing  buttonF
```

In the spaces where there is nothing in the whole column or row the minimumRowHeight and all of those settings would work. Right?

Well. The button A and button B (and the rest), never get centered over those 3 cells they share. NEVER. doesn´t matter what i write on the parameters for the layout.

I erased the code because it finally got it using a Vertical Layout, and inside, two horizontal layouts. Those get centered that way. But i would like to position them better.

What doesn't work is when adding a widget, using:

```
addWidget(widget, 0,0, 2, 0, Qt::AlignHCenter);
```

not even `AlignCenter` works.

How to make it centered or aligned to the right?

Thanks!

Comment: I found out some posts that tell to add a dummy widget expandable inside the 3 cell space. Then insert a layout on it and the widget we wanted to be centered.  Would it work? isn´t it so complicated?

Comment: As a side note, you showed a 7 x 3 grid, not a 5 x 3 one

Comment: If you want to make buttonA being stretched over 3 columns, you have to do "addWidget( widget, 0, 0, **0, 3** );" Try if this works

Comment: what?..... but it goes from column 0 to column 3 -> 4 colums!

Comment: your buttonA is in columns 0, 1, 2, then in column 3 is "nothing", then buttonB is in 4, 5, 6 (at least in the example you provided). Anyway I just wanted to point out you have to set the last number, your code stretches it over 2 rows, not 3 columns

Comment: Oh. I understood it was, the position of start (topleft corner) and the ending (bottom right corner). That´s why it goes from  0,0  to  2,0  ... but if it´s the stretch , and the numbers start on 1, then it´s 3. i´ll give it a try and i´ll check your answer (you could just write the answer down there so i can check it and you want the reputation, or i write it myself. :-)  )

Comment: I wrote a detailed answer which should clear up any misunderstanding

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The syntax of [QGridLayout::addWidget()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qgridlayout.html#addWidget-2) is like this:

> void QGridLayout::addWidget ( QWidget * widget, int fromRow, int fromColumn, **int rowSpan, int columnSpan**, Qt::Alignment alignment = 0 )

with the description:

> This version adds the given widget to the cell grid, spanning multiple rows/columns. The cell will start at fromRow, fromColumn **spanning rowSpan rows and columnSpan columns**.

This means your line

```
addWidget( widget, 0, 0, 2, 0, Qt::AlignHCenter );
```

has `fromRow = 0`, `fromColumn = 0`, `rowSpan = 2` and `columnSpan = 0`. This means it starts from row 0 and spans over two rows, i.e. it will be in row 0 and 1 (Note: Two rows in total, not two additional rows). Also it starts from column 0 with a span of 0 which I think means the column span is ignored.

So what you really want should be:

```
addWidget( widget, 0, 0, 0, 3, Qt::AlignCenter );
```

You might have to experiment with the alignment a bit.

Comment: Superb! Nice job. Thanks a lot for the nice answer